# JDK 11 Generics Issue when using Set.of

Tags: java, generics, openjdk-11, static-factory

I am unable to understand the below issue for type safety when using JDK 11. Can anyone explain the reason for not getting a compilation error when I am directly passing the `Set.of` in the argument:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var intSet1 = Set.of(123, 1234, 101);
    var strValue = "123";
    isValid(strValue, intSet1);// Compilation error (Expected behaviour)
    **isValid(strValue, Set.of(123, 1234, 101));// No Compilation error**
}

static <T> boolean isValid(T value, Set<T> range) {
    return range.contains(value);
}
```

You can run this [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wq7JVL).

Comment: @Eran Thanks for the correction, I failed to read that line's comment. I moved my IdeOne.com link into the questions for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To put it simply, the compiler is stuck with your declared types on the first call, but has some latitude to infer a compatible type on the second one.

With `isValid(strValue, intSet1);`, you're calling `isValid(String, Set<Integer>)`, and the compiler does not resolve `T` to the same type for the two arguments. This is why it's failing. The compiler simply can't change your declared types.

With `isValid(strValue, Set.of(123, 1234, 101))`, though, `Set.of(123, 1234, 101)` is a poly expression, whose type is established in the invocation context. So the compiler works at inferring `T` that is applicable in context. As Eran points out, this is `Serializable`.

Why does the first one work and the second one doesn't? It's simply because the compiler has some flexibility around the type of the expression given as the second argument. `intSet1` is a standalone expression, and `Set.of(123, 1234, 101)` is a poly expression (see the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2) and  [this description about poly expression](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Edlsmith/jsr335/jsr335-0.6.2/D.html))
. In the second case, the context allows the compiler to compute a type that works to a concrete `T` that is compatible with `String`, the first argument's type.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know the name "poly expression". But shouldn't this link go to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), since that's now the authoritative source (or maybe link to both)?

Comment: Thanks, @JoachimSauer. Will add the JLS link too. I just remembered that jsr link, being the first place I read about it.

Comment: Aren't such type of generics a bit weird and may produce vulnerability. Although testing needs to be done but still

Comment: @NishantLakhara The worst they get is *complex* and *hard to understand* for developers. But if we didn't have the benefit of poly expressions, it would be very cumbersome to program using generics (lambda expressions, as an example, would immediately become a pain). There's possibility for surprises though, when the compiler works out a type the developer didn't expect or detect, but I'm sure any tested code can easily deal with this aspect. I'm unable to see it as unsafe, though.

Comment: @JoachimSauer poly expressions are in place everywhere were generics, lambdas, etc are used. Their type depends on the context of their usage.

Comment: @Eugene: thanks, I'm well aware of what they are and what they do, I just didn't know the name of that concept.

Answer (score 9):

**isValid(strValue, Set.of(123, 1234, 101));**

When I hover with my mouse over this `isValid()` call on Eclipse, I see that it's going to execute the following method:

```
<Serializable> boolean com.codebroker.dea.test.StringTest.isValid(Serializable value, Set<Serializable> range)
```

When the compiler tries to resolve the possible type to use for the generic type parameter `T` of `isValid`, it needs to find a common super type of `String` (the type of `strValue`) and `Integer` (the element type of `Set.of(123, 1234, 101)`), and finds `Serializable`.

Therefore `Set.of(123, 1234, 101)` is resolved to `Set<Serializable>` instead of `Set<Integer>`, so the compiler can pass a `Serializable` and a`Set<Serialiable>` to `isValid()`, which is valid.

**isValid(strValue, intSet1);**

On the other hand, when you first assign `Set.of(123,1234,101)` to a variable, it is resolved to a `Set<Integer>`. And in that case, a `String` and a `Set<Integer>` cannot be passed to your `isValid()` method.

If you change

```
var intSet1 = Set.of(123, 1234, 101);
```

to

```
Set<Serializable> intSet1 = Set.of(123,1234,101);
```

Then

```
isValid(strValue, intSet1);
```

will pass compilation too.

Comment: probably Eclipse somehow simplifies this for you, but the type is [not going to be Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67807376/1059372).

Answer (score 6):

When you (as a human) look at the *second* `isValid` that compiles, probably think - how is that possible? The type `T` is inferred by the compiler to *either* `String` or `Integer`, so the call must absolutely fail.

The compiler when it looks at the method call thinks in a very different way. It looks at the method arguments, at the types provided and tries to infer an entirely different and un-expected type(s) for you. Sometimes, these types are "non-denotable", meaning types that can exist for the compiler, but you as a user, can not *declare* such types.

There is a special (un-documented) flag that you can compile your class with and have glimpse into how the compiler "thinks":

```
 javac --debug=verboseResolution=all YourClass.java
```

The output is going to be long, but the main part that we care about is:

```
  instantiated signature: (INT#1,Set<INT#1>)boolean
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>isValid(T,Set<T>)
  where INT#1,INT#2 are intersection types:
    INT#1 extends Object,Serializable,Comparable<? extends INT#2>,Constable,ConstantDesc
    INT#2 extends Object,Serializable,Comparable<?>,Constable,ConstantDesc
```

You can see that the types that are inferred and used are not `String` and `Integer`.